# An AJAX HTTP request abnormally terminated in autocomplete textbox

Tags: 7, ajax

I have autocomplete textbox which populate the suggestion based on search text.

#### Steps

1. User type in search text box
2. User press enter instead of waiting for AJAX autocomplete to respond

It comes up with the following error.

> An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
> Debugging information follows.
> Path: path/allcontent/autocomplete
> StatusText: error
> ResponseText:  ReadyState: 4

I read [Drupal alerts "An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally" during normal site operation, confusing site visitors/editors](https://www.drupal.org/node/1232416), but it didn't help.

This is the callback code.

#### Autocomplete Textbox

```
function search_user($form) {
        $form['text_usersearch'] = array(
            '#type' => 'textfield',
            '#title' => t(''),
            '#autocomplete_path' => 'searchuser/autocomplete',
            '#size' => 30,            
            '#attributes' => array('class'=> array('auto_submit'),'style'=> array('float:left')),
        );
        
$form['submit_user'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => t('Find'),
            '#attributes' => array('class'=> array('submit_user linkbuttonAction'),'style'=> array('float:left;margin-left:10px')),
       
        );
```

#### Autocomplete menu register

```
$items['searchuser/autocomplete'] = array(
     'title' => 'Autocomplete for User',
     'page callback' => 'user_autocomplete_search',
     'access arguments' => array('access content'),  //or whatever permission makes sense
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
      );
```

#### Menu callback

```
function user_autocomplete_search($string) {
        global $user;
        $arrUserMatch = array();
        
        $matchCode = '%'.db_like($string).'%';
        $arrUserTitle = SelectMatchingUserTitle($matchCode,10);            
                  
        foreach ($arrUserTitle as $userId=>$userName)
        {                                         
            $autotext .= check_plain($userName);                       
            $arrUserMatch[$userName] = $autotext;
        }
      
        drupal_json_output($arrUserMatch);        
    }
```

#### Form submission handler

```
function search_user_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   
        $searchval= $form['text_usersearch']['#value'];        
        
        if($searchval=='')
            return;
        else
           drupal_goto('user/'.$searchval); 
}
```

#### JavaScript autocomplete

```
$(window).load(function(){
                Drupal.jsAC.prototype.select = function (node) {                        
                        this.input.value = $(node).data('autocompleteValue');                                               
                        
                        if(jQuery(this.input).hasClass('auto_submit')){
                              this.input.form.submit();                     
                        }};
                              
                
        });
```

Comment: Could you show us the highlights of your code? It could be a number of things.

Comment: try to set up `'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver'` and return array of matches from your `page callback`.

Comment: I have added 'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver' line in $items['searchuser/autocomplete'] function but it didn't work. Is anything extra I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

i am using the following code to auto complete the name of the partners (store owners) in a search box in a form to edit a store's detail (not all form elements used are shown here):
the auto_complete call back returns the list of all the partners in the database.
(here one partner owns one store)
you could try and workout something similar:

the submit button links to a submit handler that updates the database.

```
function partner_store_form($form, &$form_state, $sid = 0) {
      $edit = NULL;  
      if ($sid != 0) {
      $query = db_select('store', 's')
        ->fields('s', array('partner_pid'));
      $query->leftJoin('partner', 'p', 's.partner_pid = p.pid');
      $query->condition('s.sid', $sid);
      $query->addField('p', 'name', 'p_name');
      $edit = $query->execute()->fetchObject();
      }
      $form['pid'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Partner Name'),
        '#size' => 30,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#default_value' => isset($edit) ? $edit->p_name . "  [Id:" . $edit->partner_pid . "]" : '',
        '#maxlength' => 96,
        '#autocomplete_path' => 'partner/autocomplete'
      );

      $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => isset($edit) ? t('Edit') : t('Save'),
        '#submit' => array('partner_store_form_submit')
      );
    }

    ----------

    $items['partner/autocomplete'] = array(
        'title' => 'store autocomplete',
        'page callback' => 'partner_store_autocomplete',
        'access arguments' => array(CONST_PERM_LIST_PARTNER),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      );

    -----------------

    function partner_store_autocomplete($string) {
      $store = array();
      $query = db_select('partner', 'p');
      $return = $query->fields('p', array('pid', 'name'))
        ->condition('p.name', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE')
        ->condition('p.remove', 0)
        ->execute();
      foreach ($return as $field) {
        $store[$field->name . "  [Id:" . $field->pid . "]"] = check_plain($field->name);
      }
      if (empty($store)) {
        $store[''] = t('No Such User');
      }
      drupal_json_output($store);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by an open problem to correct in Drupal core ([Drupal alerts "An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally" during normal site operation, confusing site visitors/editors](http://www.drupal.org/node/1232416#comment-10255551)). Certain developers claim that it is not a bug but a UX problem. Either way, you can apply the recommended patch until the core team backport a fix when ready for Drupal 8 ([autocomplete-1232416-218-7.37.patch](http://www.drupal.org/files/issues/autocomplete-1232416-218-7.37.patch)):

```
diff --git a/misc/ajax.js b/misc/ajax.js
index 01b894d..34831e8 100644
--- a/misc/ajax.js
+++ b/misc/ajax.js
@@ -448,7 +448,10 @@
  * Handler for the form redirection error.
  */
 Drupal.ajax.prototype.error = function (response, uri) {
-  alert(Drupal.ajaxError(response, uri));
+  if(response.status != 0) {
+    alert(Drupal.ajaxError(response, uri));
+  }
+  
   // Remove the progress element.
   if (this.progress.element) {
     $(this.progress.element).remove();
diff --git a/misc/autocomplete.js b/misc/autocomplete.js
index 5679081..ee4e336 100644
--- a/misc/autocomplete.js
+++ b/misc/autocomplete.js
@@ -307,7 +307,9 @@
         }
       },
       error: function (xmlhttp) {
-        alert(Drupal.ajaxError(xmlhttp, db.uri));
+        if (xmlhttp.status != 0) {
+          alert(Drupal.ajaxError(xmlhttp, db.uri));
+        }
       }
     });
   }, this.delay);
```

However, to avoid patching core each time Drupal needs updating, another solution, depending on how important keeping abnormal AJAX request termination error reporting alerts is for you, could be what I and a few others did by injecting a redefined Drupal behavio(u)rs AJAX error handling function as so(ish) in forms, etc. that suffer from unnecessary AJAX termination alerts:

```
(function($){
  Drupal.behaviors.YourThemeNameOrWhatever = (function(){
    return {
      attach:function(context, settings){    
        $.ajaxSetup({
          beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
            settings.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                if (window.console && console.log)
                {
                  console.log(textStatus);
                }
            };
          }
        });
      }
    }
  })();
})(jQuery);
```